# Change background-image on radio button checked

Tags: html, css, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am currently creating a form in Wordpress using gravity forms and an image plugin, that allows me to insert images instead of radio buttons. However, I would like the image to change when the radio button is checked. My issue is that I have no idea how to approach this, and how can I target the background-image when it is directly styled in the HTML?

```
   <div class='ginput_container ginput_container_radio'>
    <ul class='gfield_radio' id='input_1_2'>
     <li class='gchoice_1_2_0'><input name='input_2' type='radio' value='' id='choice_1_2_0' tabindex='1' /><label for='choice_1_2_0' id='label_1_2_0'><span class="image-choices-choice-image-wrap" style="background-image:url(http://image1.com)"><img src="http://image1.com" alt="" class="image-choices-choice-image" /></span><span class="image-choices-choice-text"></span></label></li>
     <li class='gchoice_1_2_1'><input name='input_2' type='radio' value='' id='choice_1_2_1' tabindex='2' /><label for='choice_1_2_1' id='label_1_2_1'><span class="image-choices-choice-image-wrap" style="background-image:url(http://image2.com)"><img src="http://image2.com" alt="" class="image-choices-choice-image" /></span><span class="image-choices-choice-text"></span></label></li>
     <li class='gchoice_1_2_2'><input name='input_2' type='radio' value='' id='choice_1_2_2' tabindex='3' /><label for='choice_1_2_2' id='label_1_2_2'><span class="image-choices-choice-image-wrap" style="background-image:url(http://image3.com)"><img src="http://image3.com" alt="" class="image-choices-choice-image" /></span><span class="image-choices-choice-text"></span></label></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
```

I would highly appreciate any help I can get to solve this issue.

Let me know if you need further information, thanks

Comment: Why do you use both image and background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be more specific on which image you want to change and from which radio button do you want to trigger the event. But still I'll give it a shot.

```
<input name='input_2' type='radio' value='' id='choice_1_2_0' tabindex='1' />

<div class="image-choices-choice-image-wrap" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.kimkim.com/files/a/content_articles/featured_photos/d1ea2d6f6d1aa470f661fa661bd0e2fb14fd2d2c/medium-886981758498052b0532dc3a96b98adf.jpg);height:200px;width:400px">
```

```
<script>
$('#choice_1_2_0').click(function(){
        // If radiobuton is checked
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
    // Change background image
    $('.image-choices-choice-image-wrap').css("background-image", "url(https://cdn.kimkim.com/files/a/content_articles/featured_photos/7a4f69e48562c9adbee4f090033454a8ab23c135/medium-e5cbb5b7a25c93f53245e256729efff8.jpg)");
  }
  });
</script>
```

Don't forget to add jQuery if you already haven't

Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jvh6xvzs/12/

Answer (score 1):

The generic form is:

```
input + label { /* css for unchecked state */ }
input:checked + label { /* css for checked state */ }
input { display: none; }
```

```css
input {
display: none;
}
input + label { background-color: red; }
input:checked + label { background-color: black; color: white ; }
```

```html
<input id=option1 type=radio name=dd checked><label for=option1>select</label>
<input id=option2 type=radio name=dd><label for=option2>select 2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the guide from:
https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

The plugin added the class .image-choices-choice-selected when the radio button was checked. Therefore i used following code to do the trick:

```
.image-choices-choice-selected #label_1_2_2 span[style] {
  background-image:url(http://newimage1.com) !important;
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions, I guess if this class was not added, I could have used jQuery.